# How to run another python file when a python file is finished

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

For example, I have two python file test1.py and test2.py. At first, test1.py will run. And I want test2.py to be run when the test1.py is finished.

I want the two python files run in different shell. That means test1.py should be closed when it is finished.

All the help is appreciated! Thank you!

---

I want this task to be some kind of scheduler task. At 12:00 pm the test1.py is executed. And after test1.py is finished, I want to execute test2.py automatically

Comment: Not just `python test1.py && python test2.py`? (Or using `;` instead of `&&` if the return code of the first is irrelevant.)

Comment: Thank you. But I want this task to be some kind of scheduler task. At 12:00 pm the test1.py is executed. And after test1.py is finished, I want to execute test2.py automatically.

Comment: So put the above command in the script to be executed by the task scheduler?

Comment: thank you very much! I think this will work!

Comment: You can try gearman api, check this http://gearmanhq.com/help/tutorials/Python/basic/

Comment: @PrashantPuri Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a shutdown hook to execute the other script once the first is completed with [`atexit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/atexit.html)

```
atexit.register(lambda: execfile('other.py')) # pass function to execute other file
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is going to be to do this in the shell, not using pure python. Just run `python test1.py && python test2.py` or `python test1.py; python test2.py`.

The one with && won't run test2.py if test1 fails while the one using ; will run both regardless.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I tried this method but found that the one with `;` can not run the second python file.

Comment: Not sure what the case with yours is but on my end both files run fine with either command.

Answer (score 0):

Consider there are three files. one.py is your task one, two.py is your task two and main.py is your main file which calls the other two tasks.

You can have your code something like this.

**one.py**

```
import time

class One():
    print "Before sleep one"
    time.sleep(5)
    print "After sleep one"
```

**two.py**

```
import time

class Two():
    print "Before sleep two"
    time.sleep(5)
    print "After sleep two"
```

**main.py**

```
from one import One
from two import Two

One()
Two()
```

**Output**

```
python main.py
Before sleep one
After sleep one
Before sleep two
After sleep two
```

Comment: This is wrong, importing would execute the code without the system calls.

Comment: Not if they are in a class :)

Comment: Thank you for your help. So this is like calling a method in another file.

Comment: in the above example, i just called it in a class. you can always create a new method and call that method.